# How to use with and whereHas together?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this:

```
$comments = ArticleComments::orderBy('created_at','desc')->with('user')->with('article')->with('article.translations')->paginate(10);
```

But what i want is something like this:

```
  $comments = ArticleComments::orderBy('created_at','desc')->with('user')->with('article')->with('article.translations')->whereHas('article.translations',function($query) use($default_language_id){
        $query->where('language_id','=', $default_language_id )->first();
      })->paginate(10);
```

How can i get `article.translations` but only for default language? Right now i get all translations for all languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `whereHas()` here. Use the [eager load contraining](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) feature. This code will load only `translations` for default language:

```
ArticleComments::orderBy('created_at','desc')
    ->with(['user', 'article', 'article.translations' => function($q) use(default_language_id) {
        $q->where('language_id', $default_language_id);
    }])->paginate(10);
```

Comment: but when i foreach comments and do something like this :{{ $comment->article->translations->title }}</a> i get an error that is undefined property, how can i display title form translation in view?

Comment: This should work: `{{ $comment->article->translations->first()->title }}`

Comment: thats it...tnx :)